# floatrow: Changing the formatting of table footnotes

Tags: tables, floats, formatting, footnotes, floatrow

The [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/floatrow.html) package, which is useful for customizing the layout of floats, also allows to add footnotes as well as additional explanations (besides the caption) to tables. (The main commands are `\mpfootnotemark`, `\footnotetext` and `\floatfoot`, see p. 25--26 of the manual.) One may also configure the formatting of the actual table content (to, say, `\sffamily\small`) and the explanations (to say, `\sffamily\scriptsize`). However, I have not found a way to change the formatting of footnote marks and footnote texts with `floatrow`. Any ideas?

(Notes: The `\ttabbox` command in my example, while not strictly necessary, will adapt the width of footnotes/explanations to the width of the actual table material and will also place the caption above instead of below the table. The [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/caption.html) package, which cooperates with `floatrow`, is used to change the formatting of captions.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[font={sf,small}]{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{footnoterule=none,footskip=0.5\skip\footins}

\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}
\captionsetup{footfont=scriptsize}% "footfont" defined by floatrow package

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\ttabbox{%
  % \centering% Default for floatrow package
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book\mpfootnotemark[1] \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \footnotetext[1]{\TeX\ only}%
  \floatfoot{All books listed are indispensable reading.}%
}{%
  \caption{\TeX/\LaTeX\ books}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having rummaged through `floatrow.sty` for a few hours, I think that it is a matter of omission. Footnotes in floats still use the "normal" mechanism for minipage footnotes, i.e. the formatting is not adapted to `\captionfootfont` (used for additional explanations) or `\floatfont` (used for the actual table material). Solution: Inside of floats, (EDIT:) `\@makefntext` and `\@makefnmark` need to be redefined. (For convenience, I used the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to do so.)

Note: I added a minipage to my example to show that footnotes inside minipages are not affected.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[font={sf,small}]{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{footnoterule=none,footskip=0.5\skip\footins}

\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}
\captionsetup{footfont={sf,scriptsize}}% "footfont" defined by floatrow package

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\FR@everyfloat={%
  \ifundef{\KOMAClassName}{% NEW
    \patchcmd{\@makefnmark}{\normalfont}{}{}{}% NEW
    \pretocmd{\@makefntext}{\captionfootfont}{}{}% NEW
  }{% NEW
    \renewcommand*{\ftn@font}{\captionfootfont}% NEW; for KOMA-Script-classes
  }% NEW
  \let\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
  \def\@mpfn{mpfootnote}\def\thempfn{\thempfootnote}\c@mpfootnote\z@
  \floatobjectset\floatfont
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\ttabbox{%
  % \centering% Default for floatrow package
  \begin{tabular}{cc} \hline
  Author & Title \\ \hline
  Knuth & The \TeX book\mpfootnotemark[1] \\
  Lamport & \LaTeX \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}%
  \footnotetext[1]{\TeX\ only}%
  \floatfoot{All books listed are indispensable reading.}%
}{%
  \caption{\TeX/\LaTeX\ books}%
}
\end{table}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Some text inside a minipage.\footnote{And a footnote.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Changed code example in order to also work with package [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

EDIT 2: Added code for the special footnote definition of the `KOMA-Script`-classes.

EDIT 3: Instead of duplicating the original content of the `\FR@everyfloat` token list, one may also use the LaTeX kernel macro `\addto@hook` to append code to the list's definition. See [How does one append material to a token list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38067/how-does-one-append-material-to-a-token-list) for details.

```
\makeatletter
\addto@hook{\FR@everyfloat}{%
  \ifundef{\KOMAClassName}{% NEW
    \patchcmd{\@makefnmark}{\normalfont}{}{}{}% NEW
    \pretocmd{\@makefntext}{\captionfootfont}{}{}% NEW
  }{% NEW
    \renewcommand*{\ftn@font}{\captionfootfont}% NEW; for KOMA-Script-classes
  }% NEW
}
\makeatother
```