# How to properly typeset math intervals

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have the code

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        ]-\pi,0[ \qquad -\pi \qquad \int_{-\pi}^0 \qquad [-\pi,0]
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: im]

Why is the minus sign on the left so far away from pi and how can this be avoided?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why do you want to write the brackets like that in the first place?

Comment: I think you should accept an answer since you at least have a working one. No need to keep it unanswered.

Comment: @Phill It’s a common convention for denoting (half-)open intervals. (depending on culture/language).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In the TeXbook, Knuth refers to people using “]a,b[” notation for open intervals as “perverse mathematicians” (page 171, exercise 18.14). I don't fully agree with the adjective, but I find the notation very awkward nonetheless.

There is already a package for this, which avoids reinventing the wheel:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{interval}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\interval[open]{-\pi}{0}
 \qquad
{-\pi} % this needs braces because it is between Ord atoms
 \qquad
\int_{-\pi}^0
 \qquad
\interval{-\pi}{0}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x\in\interval[open]{-\pi}{0}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The middle `-\pi` needs braces, but it's a very different problem.

See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/interval/interval.pdf) for `interval` to learn about other options.

[image]

---

#### Note about Werner's solution

Consider the following code and compile it to see what results:

```
$x \in ]{-\pi},0[$

$x \in \mathopen]-\pi,0\mathclose[$
```

(properly embed it in a standard document).

[image]

It should be clear that simply bracing `-\pi` is not sufficient.

Comment: Your answer made me smile (perhaps I am a perverse mathematician). I encountred this notation in the first book on higher mathematics I've read four years ago: Analysis I by Vladimir A. Zorich. And since then the notation stayed with me. Somehow I prefer it to $(a,b)$, since for me $(a,b)$ represents and ordered pair. Why do you find it awkward? I think it is a matter of choice.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I too suffered from the disease, because as a freshman I was taught that (French originated, possibly Bourbaki) notation. In my calculus notes I use (a .. b) for open intervals, [a .. b] for closed intervals and mix parentheses and brackets for half-open intervals; I learnt the double dot notation from a paper of Knuth's and I like it.

Comment: @egreg if `\in` is replaced with `\in\ ` in Werner solution, would it be printed correctly?

Comment: @egreg My professor uses the same notation (without the double dots). Perhaps I will like it more as time goes by. But I will definitely have a closer look on Knuths TeXbook. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou No.

Comment: @egreg: Please note that `\qquad` does *not* yield an atom, but a glue node (_The TeXbook_, p. 290; for a “glob of glue” being a different kind of node than an atom, cf. p. 157).  What changes the interpretation of the Bin atom in `-\pi` is “the *most recent* previous atom” (*not* the immediately preceding node), as explained in Appendix G, Rule 5.  So the braces around `-\pi` might be necessary, or not, depending on what comes *before* the `\qquad`: indeed, try `\interval[open]{-\pi}{0}\mathopen{} \qquad -\pi`.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Which is ignored as far as math spacing is concerned. Indeed, I noted that those braces are needed for a different reason.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek I also used square brackets $[a,b]$ in the beginning. Then I noticed that the parentheses reminded me somehow that $a$ and $b$ are limit points. The rounded shape is a bit like it gets close but never reaches. This sounded cool in my mind and I switched.

Comment: Sorry to continue on the tangent, but the double-dot notation is somewhat common for intervals of *integers*; I'd not use it for real intervals. Did Knuth really use it for *real* intervals?  (Personally I'd not use it at all, but especially not for real intervals.)

Comment: @quid My aim is just not to use the comma.

Comment: @quid Yes Knuth [recommends](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/notes/misc/notation.html) using it for real intervals as well, like [0..1] or (0..1] — see from 57:00 to about 1:07:00 in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjbuyB4dQa0&list=PLoROMvodv4rNMsVRnSJ44WuwbminUqXX2&index=14). (He credits the invention of the notation to Lyle Ramshaw and Tony Hoare.) See also pages 73–74 of _Concrete Mathematics_ where it is used.

Answer (score 28):

TeX will provide the correct spacing if you inform it that you are using `]` and `[` in a non-standard way, which can be done by means of `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`:

```
\[ \mathopen]-\pi,0\mathclose[ \]
```

This tells TeX exactly what is going on.

More precisely, TeX assumes that `[` is an Open[ing] atom and the `]` is a Close[ing] one (and I sympathize with it! ;-)  If you write

```
\[ ]-\pi,0[ \]
```

TeX will build the following list of atoms: Close, Bin, Ord, Punct, Ord, Open; this leads it to compute the difference between `]` and `\pi`, as Werner has already said; indeed, compare the above with the formula

```
(a+b)-c
```

where the minus is the second Bin atom in the resulting sequence Open, Ord, Bin, Ord, Close, Bin, Ord.

Note that Werner’s suggestion, that is,

```
]{-\pi},0[
```

yields Close, Ord{…}, Punct, Ord, Open, which does not correspond to the intended meaning, although it gives the correct spacing (but only, of course, in this particular case—see [@egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326277/69818)), as you can check in the table on p. 170 of *The TeXbook*.

IMHO, however, the best thing of all is to define an abstract command: it’s very easy to do so using the `mathtools` package and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` command; the command defined in this way provides easy means to deal with size issues: see the documentation of the `mathtools` package, subsection 3.6, for details.

Here is a complete example that illustrates both solutions:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools}

% [ bracket matching
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\openinterval}[2]{]}{[}{#1,#2}
% ] bracket matching



\begin{document}

Wrong:
\[ ]-\pi,0[ \]
Direct method, not recommended:
\[ \mathopen]-\pi,0\mathclose[ \]
With an abstract command:
\[ \openinterval{-\pi}{0} \]

Variants of the abstract command:
\begin{align*}
    &\openinterval*{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{+\frac{\pi}{2}}
            && \text{auto-resizing;}  \\
    &\openinterval[\bigg]{-\frac{\pi}{2}}{+\frac{\pi}{2}}
            && \text{with optional argument for size specification.}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

And here is the output it produces:

[image: Output of the code sample]

Answer (score 11):

TeX considers your usage as `]` minus `\pi`. Remove this ambiguity by using (say) `{-\pi}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  ]{-\pi},0[ \qquad -\pi \qquad \int_{-\pi}^0
\]

\end{document}
```

For more complex interactions, consider using [Gustavo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326251/5764). For example, to show membership or another relation/operator with respect to the set, you'll have to use an empty atom for proper spacing:

```
x \in{} ]{-\pi},0[ {}\ni x
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've just added another case, the closed interval. Why (if there is an explanation at all) does this there not happen?

Comment: Typically braces, brackets and parentheses are used in its closed form for grouping content. There's no necessary indication that `]` represents a "closed interval" to TeX... it may just as well be the end of a previous term.

Comment: Probably also, a reason is that English usage for open intervals is not `]0, π[` but `(0, π)`. At least initially, the possibility of other usages seems not to have been considered when TeX was created.

Comment: @Bernard -- these possibilities *were* considered, but the frequency with which they occur is much less than the "usual" forms, and knuth would simply have made macros that "do the right thing" instead of trying to detect such anomalous uses automatically.  i'm not able to check references at the moment, but places to look are the texbook and `manmac.tex` for a start.  index terms to check might be "open", "closed" and "interval".

Comment: I can't understand how this wrong answer got so many votes.

Comment: Just try `$x \in ]{-\pi},0[$` to see how much this is wrong. Please, remove this.

Comment: The edit doesn't really improve the quality, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

I usually care also about the *input*, readability and usability. Related to [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304685/21930), you can do something like

```
\def\intv#1]#2[{\mathopen{#1]}#2\mathclose{#1[}}
```

That way you can use easily `\intv]a,b[`, but also “extend” the size with something like `\intv\Big]a,b[`.

Full code

```
\def\intv#1]#2[{\mathopen{#1]}#2\mathclose{#1[}}
$
\intv]a,b[
\intv\big]a,b[
\intv\Bigg]\frac{a}{b},c[
$
```

Taking egreg's suggestion about `interval` package, the suggestion is still the same, to have a nice and easy to input interface, for instance

```
\usepackage{interval}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\intv#1]#2,#3[{\ifblank{#1}{\interval[open]}{\interval[open,scaled=#1]}{#2}{#3}}
..
I prefer
$x \in \intv]-\pi,0[$
rather than
$x \in \interval[open]{-\pi}{0}$
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in [my solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279029/a-robust-command-for-french-style-intervals), which allows to simply type `\interv]-a,+b[`, `\interv]{1,5},2]`, etc., with the appropriate spacing. As improved by egreg's 1st comment, it also works in headings and the table of contents.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely have a look at it, since egreg also commented there. For the moment I will stick to the package mentioned above.