# How can I automatically surround each new item in a token list with braces as delimiters?

Tags: macros, loops, recursion

I'd like to know how to create a macro that can append new elements/items to a macro list (token list) BUT also adds `{` and `}` around each added item.

**Example** I'd like it to save each new item like this:

```
\appendtocslist{tokenlist}{newitem}
```

yields `{newitem}` in the list.

**Why** Because I can easily parse the list with `\readcslist`.

I am not sure if also separating each value with a comma (or some other separator) is necessary.

## Append to Command Sequence (CS) List

- Smart enough to initiate a new macro if none exist iwth  does not exist.
- It uses csname to allow for dynamic macro names.
- It currently uses a trailing comma character , as a separator/delimiter.

Code

```
\long\def\appendtocslist#1#2{% #1 = List ID (no backslash) #2=New Item to Append
   % I chose this complicated csname form of the list-making because it can accept dynamic csnames using counters
   \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname{#2,}\else% Macro Existence Check
   \expandafter\xdef\csname#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   {\csname #1\endcsname#2,}\fi%Append expansion of #1 with #2, delimit with ,. ^^J appears as newline in terminal or space when typeset and does not work as a delimiter
}%
```

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex

\makeatletter

\long\def\appendtocslist#1#2{% #1 = List ID (no backslash) #2=New Item to Append
   % I chose this complicated csname form of the list-making because it can accept dynamic csnames using counters
   \expandafter\ifx\csname#1\endcsname\relax\expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname{#2,}\else% Macro Existence Check
   \expandafter\xdef\csname#1\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endcsname
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   {\csname #1\endcsname#2,}\fi%Append expansion of #1 with #2, delimit with ,. ^^J appears as newline in terminal or space when typeset and does not work as a delimiter
}%

\long\def\readcslist#1{%
  \@tempcnta=1%
  \checknextarg%
}
\long\def\checknextarg{%
  % My job is to check for another arg and trigger a recursive cycle.
  % for \@ifnextchar to check, so we say \bgroup, which means literal {
  % I am only important if there are exactly two args.
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\recursivecycle}{\advance\@tempcnta1\finalcall}% \@ifnextchar ignores spaces
}
\long\def\recursivecycle#1{%
  % My job is to eat each argument recursively until I
  % cannot find any more { characters. I ignore spaces.
  % If I reach the end, I run whatever is in false area of \@ifnextchar
  \advance\@tempcnta by 1% add one for next arg
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\recursivecycle}{\finalcall}}
\def\finalcall{Total n of args: \the\@tempcnta}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hello.
\appendtocslist{mylist}{a}
\appendtocslist{mylist}{b}
\appendtocslist{mylist}{c}

\readcslist{d}{e}{f}

% \expandafter\readargs\expandafter{\mylist} % wouldn't this be nice!%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want also the comma?

Comment: @egreg Glad you asked first. What do you recommend from your knowledge of dealing with these things? Is it necessary if I have everything surrounded in braces for future manipulation e.g. element extraction or prepending/appending new elements?

Comment: I would avoid to reinvent the wheel and use `expl3`. And definitely not absorb items until no more `{` are found. This is very dangerous and useless: `\readcslist{{a}{b}{c}}` is much simpler and safer.

Comment: @egreg I was trying to avoid expl3, not to undermind the project or your efforts.

Comment: What's the connection between `\appendtocslist` and `\readcslist`? I see none.

Comment: @egreg `\readcslist` just parses `{}` arguments. Other than that, they are separate entities. It is probably misnamed unless I rework the definition to accept a command sequence as in input.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?  The `listofitems` package is real good at parsing lists. and it is not `expl3` (in fact, it is plain TeX).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Oh really? That is a good tip. I will have a look at the source code. I am just trying to get better at writing code in TeX for kicks. After looking around, I could only find anwers that provided hardcoded (literal) token lists with braces around items. E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52653/how-does-one-remove-material-from-a-token-list

Comment: @egreg @egreg I just looked at my *actual* implementation (as opposed to the minimal example here), and I do use a function that recursively (recklessly?) looks for `{`, but it only does this until an `\end{myenv}` is encountered. In other words, it is wrapped within a function and works similarly to `\item`, I think.

Comment: `\item` doesn't scan forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% syntactic sugar
\def\expandtwice{\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}
% append to list (or create it)
\newcommand\appendtocslist[2]{%
  % #1 = Macro Name without \ (list name), #2=New Item to Append
  \ifcsname#1\endcsname
    \expandafter\xdef\csname#1\endcsname{%
      % the previous items
      \expandtwice{\csname#1\endcsname}%
      % the new item
      {#2}%
    }%
  \else
    % the list doesn't exist yet, create it
    \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{{#2}}
  \fi
}
% read n-argument types (ignoring spaces)
\long\def\readcslist#1{%
  \@tempcnta=1
  \checknextarg
}
\long\def\checknextarg{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\recursivecycle}{\finalcall}%
}
\long\def\recursivecycle#1{%
  \advance\@tempcnta by 1 % add one for next arg
  \checknextarg
}
\def\finalcall{Total n of args: \the\@tempcnta}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hello.
\appendtocslist{mylist}{a}
\appendtocslist{mylist}{b}
\appendtocslist{mylist}{c}

\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname mylist\endcsname}

\readcslist{d}{e}{f}

\expandafter\readcslist\mylist

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just realized that `\xdef` should be `\protected@xdef` to maintain the effect of `\protect` when appending things like `\textit` or `\textbf`. Obviously, you used my minimal example, but I wanted to note this here for posterity.

Comment: @JonathanKomar Yes, that would be necessary if `#2` contains “dangerous” items.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the question "I'd like to know how to create a macro that can append new elements/items to a macro list (token list) BUT also adds { and } around each added item."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newtoks\mylist
\newcommand\addtotoklist[2]{#1\expandafter{\the#1{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\addtotoklist\mylist{a}
\addtotoklist\mylist{b}
\addtotoklist\mylist{cde}
\detokenize\expandafter{\the\mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good stuff. I think it helps to know that this is shortened form of `\newcommand\addtotoklist[2]{#1=\expandafter{\the#1{#2}}}
`. In other words, skip ahead to expand the list as it is first, then put `#2` after it, then the whole line of junk (tokens) will be assigned to `#1`.