# \expandafter in the definition of vaerbatim

Tags: macros, verbatim

I'm now reading the source code of LaTeX.

In the definition of `verbatim` environment (`\@verbatim`, exactly), there is something like

```
\everypar \expandafter{\the\everypar \unpenalty}
```

What does this `\expandafter` do?

I only know that `\expandafter` can delay expansion like

```
\expandafter\def\csname test-cmd\endcsname
```

But what will happen if the token after `\expandafter` is a `}`?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451/100689

Comment: `\everypar` is a token list register, so you need to delay the expansion of the brace in order to append material to it. You find detailed explanations [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33849/82917) (about `\everypar`) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38085/82917) (about `\expandafter{`).

Comment: Dupe of one or both of those?

Comment: @campa Still not fully understand. Why this assignment must be ended with an explicit `}`?

Comment: A token list `\foo` is usually assigned by `\foo{some token list}`. The opening brace so to say "starts" the assignment mechanism. Here we want to append something to the token list, so we need to freeze the assignment mechanism until the token list is expanded. The closing brace is of course necessary in order to mark the end of the assignment.

Comment: I noticed that even `\everypar=\bgroup Hello\egroup` will raise an error. Is it a mechanism on TeX level?

Comment: @Stone-Zeng (I've seen your comment by chance: you have to ping with `@name`) The closing brace _must_ be explicit.