# Adding both captions and notes to a table with the captions package

Tags: tables, floats, captions

In the following table I created the caption exactly they way I wanted. I'd like to add a "Note" below the `tabular`, but within the `table` environment, following the same style as the caption. I sort of achieved what I wanted with the following. But it seems very hacky. There must be a better way, right? E.g., is there some starred version of `\caption` that suppresses the float number? If there were I could just add that below the `tabular`. That sure would be easiest. I've checked the `caption` package and there seems to be no such thing. Any other solutions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon,tableposition=top,figureposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[leftmargin=10pt,rightmargin=10pt]{quoting}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      foo & bar \\
      \midrule
      baz & bog \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{quoting}
      {\small {\bf Note:} a note Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
    \end{quoting}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tab1]

Comment: The `floatrow` package might be of interest. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9547/floatrow-changing-the-font-of-table-footnotes

Comment: The `caption` package actually do offer `\caption*`. See section 3.1 "Typesetting captions" of the `caption` package documentation. Other option (beside using self-defined commands) is using one of the packages which offers table notes, e.g. the `threeparttable` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and its `\floatfoot` macro.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon,tableposition=top,
    figureposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\captionsetup{footfont=small}% "footfont" defined by floatrow package
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[ht]
%     \centering% default with "floatrow"
    \caption{My caption. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
      \toprule
      foo & bar \\
      \midrule
      baz & bog \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \floatfoot{\textbf{Note:} a note Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}%
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great stuff. I'm playing with your code now. I was wondering, why do you need to use `\captionsetup{footfont=small}` rather than setting the `footfont` parameter in the package declaration with `\usepackage[capposition=top,footfont=small]{floatrow}`? I've noticed the latter doesn't work (ends up using the default `footnotesize` for the `footfont`). Why? Is this a bug?

Comment: @brianjd According to section 3.1.2 of the `floatrow` manual, the *"`\floatfoot` macro uses `caption` package’s mechanism and utilities`"*.