# Modify Floatfoot of Floatrow Package and move Rule

Tags: captions, rules, floatrow, footer

From the `floatrow` package, I am using the `floatfoot` command to reference sources and similar content.

This MWE produces an output that is quite acceptable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{floatrow}
        \floatsetup[figure]%
        {%
            capbesideposition=right,%
            postcode=rule,%
        }%
    \setlength{\floatfootskip}{0pt}%remove vertical space/skip
\usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionFont{ftfont}{\scriptsize\raggedleft}
    \captionsetup[floatfoot]
        {%
            footfont=ftfont,%
        }%      
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
        {%
            \rule{5cm}{5cm}
        }%
        {%
            \caption{None}%
            \floatfoot{Floatfoot}%  
        }%
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \fcapside[\FBwidth]
        {%
            \rule{5cm}{5cm}
        }%
        {%
            \caption{None}%
            \floatfoot{Floatfoot}%  
        }%
    \end{figure}    
    \begin{table}
        \ttabbox
        {%
            \caption{None}%
            \floatfoot{Floatfoot}
        }%
        {%
            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                \hline
                Number & Name\\
                2 & Fred\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        }%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

The Table is inserted for good measure, it looks good as-is. I am concerned about the figures.

I have not been able to find information in the package doc about modifying the `floatfoot`. Its positional commands (`default`, `caption`, `bottom`) are not what I am looking for.

Additionally, the horizontal rule underneath the float is a nice touch in my mind.

1. **As a first step, is there a way to place this rule from `postcode` *above* the `floatfoot`?**
   This cannot be that hard, however I failed. Fiddling with `midcode` etc. did not solve it.
2. **Secondly, a much more advanced question. It might not be reasonable. Is there a way to mold the `rule` and `floatfoot` into something like this:**

[image]

Excuse the sketch.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `\footnotetext` instead of `\floatfoot` ?

Comment: I am not aware of what `\footnotetext` does exactly. Is it not bound to also having a footnote-mark? `floatrow` makes a distinction there, and offers footnotes but also `\floatfoot`, for additional, arbitrary explanations. I thought it would fit for my intentions. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9547/floatrow-changing-the-formatting-of-table-footnotes) showcases the difference nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hiatus, I have returned to the issue and now solved it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{slash}{\ /\ }%
    \DeclareCaptionFont{ftfont}{\scriptsize\color{red}\hypersetup{hidelinks}\sffamily\raggedleft}
    \captionsetup{%
        format=plain,%
        textformat=period,%
        font=small,%all fonts
        labelfont={sf,bf},%
        labelsep=slash,%
        labelformat=simple,%just Name/Number, no period or similar
        indention=1em,%
    }%
    \captionsetup[floatfoot]%
                    {%
                        footfont=ftfont,%
                    }%
\usepackage{floatrow}%
    \floatsetup{footnoterule=none}%avoid drawing two rules
    \floatsetup[figure]%
                    {%
                        capbesideposition=right,%
                        capbesidesep=quad,%
                    }%  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newlength{\floatfootruleindent}
\makeatletter
    \setlength{\floatfootruleindent}{\caption@indent}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\floatfootskip{2pt\hspace{\floatfootruleindent}\hrulefill}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]
        {%
            \caption{My caption which is longer than usual so it spans more than one line}
            \floatfoot{This is the float foot}
%           \footnotetext[1]{A footnote.}
        }%
        {%
            \rule{4cm}{4cm}%\mpfootnotemark[1]
        }%
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
    \fcapside[\FBwidth]
    {%
        \caption{My caption which is longer than usual so it spans more than one line}
        \floatfoot{This is the float foot}
        \footnotetext[1]{A footnote.}
    }%
    {%
        \rule{4cm}{4cm}\mpfootnotemark[1]
    }%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is a misuse of `\floatfootskip` as far as I can see, which seems to be intended to just be a length. The first input `2pt` provides the length the package expects, but then also inserts all the code behind it.

It works for now. I am an absolute beginner in fiddling with `.sty` definitions, so I am certain this is an awful way to do it. Especially the way how `\floatfootskip` is also used for `\footnotetext`, which results in another `\hrulefill` to be drawn, even if we don't want this. The default is to draw a shorter line, removed here by `footrulerule=none`.

Still, I hope people could be interested in this.

The results looks like[image]